# Legal or out-of-bounds forming the address of the first element past the end?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

In another question I saw `&studmark[STUDNO][0]` where `STUDNO` is the size of the array.

I wonder now if that code is already undefined behaviour. `studmark[STUDNO]` is one-past-the-end and while it may be created it must not be accessed. Is indexing that with `[0]` to then form the address valid? Or must one use simply `studmark[STUDNO]` which then degrades to a pointer one-past-the-end?

Arguments either way please with references to the standard.

Update: Sample code and output

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STUDNO 16

int studmark[STUDNO][2];

int main() {
  printf("&studmark = %p\n", studmark);
  printf("&studmark[1][0] = %p\n", &studmark[1][0]);
  printf("&studmark[STUDNO-1][0] = %p\n", &studmark[STUDNO-1][0]);
  printf("&studmark[STUDNO][0] = %p\n", &studmark[STUDNO][0]);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling gives no warnings and outputs:

```
./foo 
&studmark = 0x601060
&studmark[1][0] = 0x601068
&studmark[STUDNO-1][0] = 0x6010d8
&studmark[STUDNO][0] = 0x6010e0
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that the definition of `studmark` looks like this:

```
int studmark[STUDNO][2];
```

Then the expression `&studmark[STUDNO][0]` invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To make the pointer dereferences more apparent, first we'll switch from array index notation from pointer notation.  Section 6.5.2.1p2 of the C11 standard states:

> The definition of the subscript operator `[]` is that `E1[E2]` is
>   identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`

So the above expression becomes:

```
&*(studmark[STUDNO] + 0)
```

Which becomes:

```
&*(*(studmark + STUDNO) + 0)
```

This expression starts with the `&` and `*` operators.  When `&` preceedes `*` they cancel each other out.  This spelled out in section 6.5.3.2p3:

> The unary `&` operator yields the address of its operand. If the
>   operand has type "type", the result has type "pointer to type". **If the
>   operand is the result of a unary `*` operator, neither that operator
>   nor the `&` operator is evaluated and the result is as if both were
>   omitted**, except that the constraints on the operators still apply and
>   the result is not an lvalue.

So this can be reduced to:

```
*(studmark + STUDNO) + 0
```

Now we look at the addition.  This is valid because creating a pointer to one element past the end of the array is legal as per section 6.5.6p8:

> When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted
>   from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the
>   pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array
>   is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the
>   original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the
>   resulting and original array elements equals the integer expression.
>   In other words, if the expression `P` points to the *i*<sup>th</sup>
>   element of an array object, the expressions `(P)+N` (equivalently,
>   `N+(P)`) and `(P)-N` (where `N` has the value *n*) point to,
>   respectively, the *i+n*<sup>th</sup> and *i−n*<sup>th</sup> elements
>   of the array object, provided they exist. Moreover, if the expression
>   `P` points to the last element of an array object, the expression
>   `(P)+1` points one past the last element of the array object, and if
>   the expression `Q` points one past the last element of an array
>   object, the expression `(Q)-1` points to the last element of the array
>   object. **If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements
>   of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array
>   object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
>   behavior is undefined.** If the result points one past the last element
>   of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary
>   `*` operator that is evaluated.

This means `studmark + STUDNO` is a valid pointer, but it cannot be dereferenced.  This is where the problem comes in.  `*(studmark + STUDNO)` invokes undefined behavior because it dereferences one element past the end of the array.

So `&studmark[STUDNO][0]` is undefined behavior.

In contrast, this is valid:

```
&studmark[STUDNO]
```

As it is equal to:

```
&*(studmark + STUDNO)
```

And subsequently:

```
studmark + STUDNO
```

Because it creates a pointer to one element past the end of an array but does not dereference  it.

Comment: It's `int studmark[STUDNO][2];` (updated question as I think it makes a difference) So an array of STUDNO * 2 ints unless I'm mistaken, or `&(*(studmark + STUDNO * 2 + 0))`. Your `&*(*(studmark + STUDNO) + 0)` would happen when the array is `int *studmark[STUDNO]`, an array of pointers to arrays of ints. Right?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow It doesn't matter what size the second dimension is.  `studmark[STUDNO]` is UB because it accesses an array object one past the end of the first array dimension.

Comment: I don't necessarily disagree about the UB. As I say in the question it looks fishy. But which element of the array is actually accessed? Because all I see is address calculation. `studmark + STUDNO` is a valid pointer and then 0 is added. It's not actually dereferenced as in your answer, just 0 is added. I've added test code to the question to show the effect.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow You're not adding 0 to `studmark + STUDNO`.  You're adding 0 to `*(studmark + STUDNO)`.  That's the illegal dereference.

Comment: I'm not. Look at the end of 6.5.2.1 at the example for `int x[3][5];` Specifically: `The results are added and indirection is applied to yield an array of five ints. When used in the expression x[i][j], that array is in turn converted to a pointer to the first of the ints, so x[i][j] yields an int.` If you will it's &*(&*(studmark + STUDNO) + 0). There is no array containing pointers to the rows that has to be accessed as `*(studmark + STUDNO)` would imply.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Read more closely: "The results are added and indirection is applied **to yield an array of five ints**." So after the first array indexing you have an array object, not a pointer, and `studmark[STUDNO]` is a nonexistent array object.  `[]` has higher precedence than `&`, so the second array indexing is applied before the `&`.  Also, you're adding an extra `&` in your sample that doesn't exist.  Look again at my answer where I convert the array indexing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202354/discussion-between-goswin-von-brederlow-and-dbush).